# Canot not get user facebook messager into rasa core server

Tags: python, facebook, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I built a slack bot with rasa core and nlu and it is working fine. I can easily process user input. But when I tried the same process with facebook channel, my rasa facebook app is not responding  if some user say any thing in page messenger.

My webhook is working fine.

> ```
> se 'load(stream, Loader=ruamel.yaml.Loader)' explicitly if that is OK.
> ```
>
> Alternatively include the following in your code:
>
> import warnings
>     warnings.simplefilter('ignore', ruamel.yaml.error.UnsafeLoaderWarning)
>
> In most other cases you should consider using 'safe_load(stream)'
>     data = yaml.load(stream) 
>   127.0.0.1 - - [2018-11-16 10:52:50] "GET /webhooks/slack/webhook?hub.mode=subscribe&  hub.challenge=343235800&hub.verify_token=rasa-bot HTTP/1.1" 404 342 0.005916
>   127.0.0.1 - - [2018-11-16 10:53:51] "GET /webhooks/facebook/webhook?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=923059630&hub.verify_token=rasa-bot HTTP/1.1" 200 124 0.001723

and here is my server script.

```
nlu_interpreter = RasaNLUInterpreter('./models/default/model_20181116-102101')
action_endpoint = EndpointConfig(url="http://localhost:5055/webhook")
agent = Agent.load('./models/dialogue', interpreter=nlu_interpreter, action_endpoint=action_endpoint)


credentials = yaml.load(open('./credentials.yml'))
fb_access_token = credentials['facebook']['verify']
fb_secret = credentials['facebook']['secret']
fb_verify = credentials['facebook']['verify']

input_channel = FacebookInput(fb_access_token=fb_access_token,fb_secret=fb_secret,  fb_verify=fb_verify)

logLevel = "DEBUG"
logfile = "log.txt"


utils.configure_colored_logging(logLevel)
utils.configure_file_logging(logLevel, logfile)

agent.handle_channels([input_channel], 5004, serve_forever=True)
```

Do I have to extend import some class to process user message. Because during slack bot, it was not needed. I am using rasa core 0.11.12 and latest rasa NLU.

I am not receiving user message in my rasa server.

Any help guys.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
fb_access_token = credentials['facebook']['verify']
```

to

```
fb_access_token = credentials['facebook']['page-access-token']
```

In general I recommend using Rasa Core from the command line instead of writing custom code. For example you can instruct Core to set up Facebook as channel by providing a credentials file like

```
facebook:
  verify: "rasa-bot"
  secret: "1234"
  page-access-token: "3123020"
```

and then starting Rasa Core with:

```
python -m rasa_core.run -d models/dialogue \
   -u models/nlu/current \
   --credentials credentials.yml
```

This is also documented in the [Rasa Core docs](https://rasa.com/docs/core/connectors/#facebook-setup).